# Tkinter Python Automatic Shop Rota System

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a rota system that automatically adds staff to a rota depending on their rank(management or sales assistant) and their availability. However, I'm having some issues with my code, mainly the GUI which doesn't want to to work for me.

This is part of the code, the issue here is that it currently will not output the data to the list box even though when the program runs no errors occur. I'm in need of serious help, with this and the rest of the issues.

```html
def __init__(self):

        self.window = Tk()

        self.window.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.close)

        self.window.title("View Management")

        self.window.config(background='#ccffcc')

        self.department_lst = Listbox(self.window,width=50,height=15)

        self.department_lst.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=3)

        #Department Menu

        self.department_lbl = Label(self.window,text = 'Department')

        self.department_lbl.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.department_lbl.config(background='#ccffcc')

        options = ['Adults','Childrens']

        self.department_option_var = StringVar()

        self.department_option_var.trace('w',lambda name,index,mode: self.write_lst())

        self.department_option_menu = OptionMenu(self.window,self.department_option_var, *options)

        self.department_option_menu.configure(width=12,background='#ccffcc')

        self.department_option_menu.grid(row=1,column=1)



    def write_lst(self):

        self.department_lst.delete(0,END)

        for management in my_users.get_management():

            if management.get_department()==self.department_option_var.get():

                self.department_lst.insert(END, management.get_ID() + '\n')
```

Comment: What does "doesn't want to work for me" mean? Are you getting errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: Maybe the error is elsewhere; Can you post the code for the my_users.get_management() part? It could be that somehow there is nothing stored in that object.